# How do I import multiple tables from a single NetCDF .nc file using python xarray?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a dataset in both a netcdf .nc file and a .wls file. I can open the .wls file and view it with a text editor. The dataset contains a large amount of metadata and several tables. I understand that python xarray was created  to work with netcdf files, but when I try to import this file as a python xarray dataset, only one of the tables is imported.

This information is copied from the text file. Each table ends with `%TableEnd:`, so I think the import ends there. Most of my data is in .nc files, so manually editing text files isn't an option.

```
%CTF: 1.00
%FileType: WVMD WVM9 "Wave History"
%UUID: 1E9EBB39-F35C-4E9B-8C4C-72945FFEA5D9
%Manufacturer: CODAR Ocean Sensors. SeaSonde
...
(trimmed for clarity)
...
%TableType: WAVL WVM9
%TableColumns: 20
%TableColumnTypes: TIME MWHT MWPD WAVB WNDB PMWH ACNT DIST RCLL WDPT MTHD FLAG WHNM WHSD TYRS TMON TDAY THRS TMIN TSEC 
%TableRows: 4459
%TableStart:
%%     Time     ----------Wave----------    Wind    WaveNF                                                             Height    Height                        
%%   FromStart   Height  Period   From      From    Height   Spectra   Distance   Range   Doppler    Wave    Vector    Valid      StdDv    Time                
%%   (seconds)     (m)     (s)   (True)    (True)     (m)     count      (km)      cell     bins    Method    Flag     points      (m)     Year Mo Dy  Hr Mn  S
             0      1.21   5.75    19.0     77.3      0.19        7    9.06088        3       20        2        0          4      0.19    2019 10 01  00 00 00
           600      1.16   5.60    17.5     75.2      0.19        7    9.06088        3       20        2        0          5      0.20    2019 10 01  00 10 00
          1200      1.16   5.60    17.5     75.2      0.19        7    9.06088        3       20        2        0          5      0.20    2019 10 01  00 20 00

...
...
       2677200      2.41   7.00   101.0    217.0      0.20        7    9.06088        3       26        2        0          5      0.13    2019 10 31  23 40 00
       2677800      2.37   7.00   101.0    217.0      0.21        7    9.06088        3       26        2        0          5      0.09    2019 10 31  23 50 00
%TableEnd:
%%
%Distance: 12.08117 km
%RangeCell: 4
%TableType: WAVL WVM9
%TableColumns: 20
%TableColumnTypes: TIME MWHT MWPD WAVB WNDB PMWH ACNT DIST RCLL WDPT MTHD FLAG WHNM WHSD TYRS TMON TDAY THRS TMIN TSEC 
%TableRows: 4459
%TableStart: 2
%%     Time     ----------Wave----------    Wind    WaveNF                                                             Height    Height                        
%%   FromStart   Height  Period   From      From    Height   Spectra   Distance   Range   Doppler    Wave    Vector    Valid      StdDv    Time                
%%   (seconds)     (m)     (s)   (True)    (True)     (m)     count      (km)      cell     bins    Method    Flag     points      (m)     Year Mo Dy  Hr Mn  S
             0    999.00 999.00     0.0     67.0      0.18        7   12.08117        4       19        2       64          0      0.00    2019 10 01  00 00 00
...
...
```

Here is the xarray code i tried. There should be 7 tables of 4459 values.

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('filename.nc')
ds.sizes

Output:
Frozen(SortedKeysDict({'time': 4459}))
```

Comment: Variables are different than dimensions in xarray.  Your variables (columns) are likely listed as variables.  Print ds (not ds.sizes) to verify.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was that the two files were different. The .nc file did not contain the same information as the txt file.